# How to read from a string delimited kafka topic then convert it to json?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm currently working on a POC project that uses Kafka Connect to read from a Kafka topic to write to database. I am aware that JDBC sink connectors requires schema to work. However all of our kafka topics are string delimited. Apart from creating a new topic with json or avro, I'm planning to create an API that converts string to json, any possible solutions that I can try?

Comment: I would suggest using a stream processor, not "an API"

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem would be creating a custom Converter. Unfortunately, there is no blog post or online resource on how to do that step by step but you can have a look over how the [StringConverter](https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/StringConverter.java) has been built. It's a pretty straightforward API that uses Serializers and Deserializers to convert the data.

L.E:

A converter uses Serializers and Deserializers so the only thing that you should do is to create your own:

```
public class StringConverter implements Converter {

   private final CustomStringSerializer serializer = new CustomStringSerializer();
   private final CustomStringSerializer deserializer = new CustomStringSerializer();

   --- boilerplate code resulted by implementing the converter Interface ---

      @Override
    public byte[] fromConnectData(String topic, Schema schema, Object value) {
        try {
            return serializer.serialize(topic, value == null ? null : value.toString());
        } catch (SerializationException e) {
            throw new DataException("Failed to serialize to a string: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAndValue toConnectData(String topic, byte[] value) {
        try {
            return new SchemaAndValue(createYourOwnSchema(topic, value), deserializer.deserialize(topic, value));
        } catch (SerializationException e) {
            throw new DataException("Failed to deserialize string: ", e);
        }
    }

}
```

You can notice that `toConnectData` is returning a `SchemaAndValue` object and actually it is exactly what you need to customize. You can create your own `createYourOwnSchema` method that will create the schema based on the topic ( and the value? ) and then you have the deserializer that will deserialize your data.

Comment: KSQL would work as well, assuming there's a string split function

Comment: Thank you so much for both of your input. I'm sorry if this would seem stating the obvious but I just need reassurance that it's possible to create a custom converter that consumes from a string delimited kafka topic then i would add a method to include schema to every message. Did I get it right? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Short answer: yes! I've added some implementation details about how you can do that using Converters.

Comment: Great help! Thank you so much for this. Correct me if I'm wrong please. If I get this right, the converters are part of the whole kafka connect framework right? If I were to create a custom converter, do I need to create a whole framework from consuming to the kafka topic up to the utlization of the converter? I'm sorry please be patient.

Comment: @Isabelle no need to apologize! 1. Yes, Converters are part of the Kafka Connect framework. 2. No, since Converters are part of the Kafka Connect framework, the only thing you have to do it to install it on your workers ( just like you install a new connector, link here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/install.html#install-connector-manually/ )  and then, during the deployment of your connector, you can specify which Converter it should use: e.g ... "value.converter": "com.custom.converter.MyCustomConverter" ....

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your use case, I would definitely try Kafka Streams to process your delimited String topic and sink it into a JSON topic. Then, you can use this JSON topic as input to your database.

With Kafka Streams, you can map each String record of your topic and apply logic into it to generate a JSON with your data. The processed records could be sinked into your results topic just as Strings with JSON format or even as a JSON Type using the Kafka JSON Serdes ([Kafka Streams DatatTypes](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html)).

This approach also adds flexibility with your input data, you can process, transform or ignore each delimited field of your string.

If you want to get started, check out the [Kafka Demo](https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/quickstart) and the [Confluent Kafka-Streams examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/5.3.1-post/src/main) for more complex use cases.

Comment: Good input! I will look into this. Thank you so much for accommodating my query. However, do you know any way I can do this by not creating/ingesting to another topic instead directly inserting it to the database?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think its possible to use a database as output of a Kafka Streams application. Kafka Streams is built to process data stored in a Kafka Topic with the Source processor and using your Kafka cluster as output via Sink processor. You should use Kafka Connect if you want to move data from Kafka to a database, but I recomend using Kafka Streams to acomodate your data first. This example sumarizes the workflow: https://www.confluent.io/blog/hello-world-kafka-connect-kafka-streams/

Answer (score 0):

Let's create Kafka Streams application. You will consume data as
`KStream<String, String>` (assumption that key also is the `String`)
and than in Kafka Stream app transform it to `KStream<String,YourAvroClass>` and produce messages to target `Avro` topic.

```
KStream<String, String> sourceStream ....
sourceStream
  .mapValues(value -> new YourAvroClass(...), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), yourAvroClassSerde))
  .to("avro-output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), yourAvroClassSerde));
```